# Is $y'(x) = y(y(x))$ an ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm starting the course of ordinary differential equations and I'm not really sure if $y'(x) = y(y(x))$ is an ODE. More than the answer what I need is an explanation of the reason of it.

Thanks!

Comment: The last quote in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/33153/415941) post says *No*. But it gives no reason.

Comment: An ODE of first order can be written as $y'=F(x,y).$ Can you write $y(y(x))=F(y(x))?$

Comment: @mfl One should be very precise about the types of objects here, since in some sence I *can* write $y(y(x)) = F(y(x))$, just take $F=y$ (lexically).

Comment: @lisyarus Yes, you are right. I mean $F$ independent of $x,y.$ Thank you for pointing it.

Comment: If $y$ is a constant function, then yes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually an $n$-th order ODE is defined as a function $F:\Bbb R\times\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R$ and a pair $(x_0;y_0,y_1,...,y_{n-1})\in\Bbb R\times\Bbb R^n$. The fact that ODEs talk about functions only comes into the game when we define what we consider a *solution* of this ODE. A solution is an $n$ times differentiable function $y:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ with

$$y^{(k)}(x_0)=y_k\text{ for }k=0,...,n-1,\qquad y^{(n)}(x)=F(x;y(x),y'(x),...,y^{(n-1)}(x)).$$

But $y(y(x))$ only makes sense when we already talk about functions when stating the ODE.

**Conclusion**. So I do not consider $y'(x)=y(y(x))$ an ODE, but I think this is still debatable. It is some "weird" problem statement mixing elements from differential and functional equations.

Comment: Do you mean that the composition doesn't make sense because at first we are consideing y(x) a variable of function F?

Comment: @SergiDelaTorre Yes. Somehow. $y$ in $F$ is just a real number. You cannot compose real numbers. You can state an ODE without even mentioning functions.

Comment: Looks like you have a typo: $y$ should be $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @lisyarus Thank you very much! There were actually more mistakes but I fixed them hopefully!

Comment: I think that a possible good term for this would be a *functional-differential equation* :)

Comment: @lisyarus Actually, I think checking whether $y'(x)=y(y(x))$ has any non-trivial solutions besides $y(x)=0$ might be an interesting problem!

Comment: @M.Winter Yes, for sure!