# An extremely rigorous and formal definition of differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, definition

I actually asked a version of this question before, here: [What is the formal, rigorous definition of a differential equation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4328632/what-is-the-formal-rigorous-definition-of-a-differential-equation). However, I should have asked what an equation is, first, which I did here: [What is the formal definition of an equation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4329160/what-is-the-formal-definition-of-an-equation). But now that I have asked the question of what an equation is, and gotten a very detailed and rigorous answer, I want to revisit my original question. I want to know what is the formal and rigorous definition of a differential equation. I don't think it is simply a functional equation, like $f^2=f+1$. That is an equation involving real functions, but it is not a differential equation. So, then, what is the definition of differential equations?

Comment: What makes the definition of ODE we learn in class non rigorous?

Comment: @KurtG. A differential equation is not an equation relating functions and their derivatives. For example, $\dot x=x(x(t))$ is not a differential equation.

Comment: VI Arnold defines an ordinary differential equation as determined by a vector field. See "Ordinary Differential Equations", chapter 2 by VI Arnold.

Comment: There is a good answer given for ODEs given by Pacciu [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33153/definition-of-a-differential-equation?rq=1). A similar answer works for PDEs you just have to use partial derivatives and ibstead of an open interval use an open connected subset in the variable space.

Comment: @JohnDouma I learned the Arnold definition. It is rigorous.

Comment: @KurtG. I upvoted this question because an internet search for the definition of an ordinary differential equation does not yield a rigorous definition. The definition given by Arnold is surprisingly elusive.

Comment: @user107952: Does this answer it https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33153/definition-of-a-differential-equation?rq=1? What is missing there that is different? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33153/definition-of-a-differential-equation?rq=1

Comment: @Moo: If you limit yourself to ODEs, then this is indeed a duplicate, but the link does not provide a definition of a PDE. See my comment above. In tags, OP says "ODEs", but not in the body of the question.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: I can only go by what the question contains. I did not flag it, but it seems like a dupe to me. Regards.